# ElasticSearch gives error about queue size

Tags: elasticsearch

> RemoteTransportException[[Death][inet[/172.18.0.9:9300]][bulk/shard]]; nested: EsRejectedExecutionException[rejected execution (queue capacity 50) on org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction$1@12ae9af];

Does this mean I'm doing too many operations in one bulk at one time, or too many bulks in a row, or what? Is there a setting I should be increasing or something I should be doing differently?

One thread suggests "I think you need to increase your 'threadpool.bulk.queue_size' (and possibly 'threadpool.index.queue_size') setting due to recent defaults." However, I don't want to arbitrarily increase a setting without understanding the fault.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You want to up the number of bulk threads available in the thread pool. ES sets aside threads in several named pools for use on various tasks. These pools have a few settings; type, size, and queue size.

from the docs:

> The queue_size allows to control the size of the queue of pending
>   requests that have no threads to execute them. By default, it is set
>   to -1 which means its unbounded. When a request comes in and the queue
>   is full, it will abort the request.

To me that means you have more bulk requests queued up waiting for a thread from the pool to execute one of them than your current queue size. The documentation seems to indicate the queue size is defaulted to both -1 (the text above says that) and 50 (the call out for bulk in the doc says that). You could [take a look at the source](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch) to be sure for your version of es OR set the higher number and see if your bulk issues simply go away.

[ES thread pool settings doco](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-threadpool.html)

Comment: To clarify, is this the total number of bulk calls, or the number of bulk operations inside each request? i.e. does 2 bulk calls that contain 30 ops each cause this issue or does only 50+ bulk calls of any count cause it?

Comment: I would have to read source to be sure, my total blind guess is that a bulk call of size N is handled by one thread, not N threads. Otherwise a bulk call of 5000 (something I have done while moving data around between clusters) would house my setup.

Comment: That does seem to make sense. Is there a way to see the current number of items of the queue?

Comment: the es stats api pretty much has everything, check it out here : http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-nodes-stats.html

Comment: just looked at stats for my work cluster and see very few threads even on the nodes doing ingest via a river, so I dont think it spins up a thread per doc.. still not totally sure.

Comment: Just as a note, if you are using AWS Elasticsearch Service you cannot increase the thread pool allocation of bulk indexing beyond 50 ( https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=682728 ). You will just have to write an exception handling for this situation.

Answer (score 38):

I lack the reputation to reply to the comment as a comment.

It's not exactly the number of bulk requests made, it is actually the total number of shards that will be updated on a given node by the bulk calls. This means the contents of the actual bulk operations inside the bulk request actually matter. For instance, if you have a single node, with a single index, running on an 8 core box, with 60 shards and you issue a bulk request that has indexing operations that affects all 60 shards, you will get this error message with a single bulk request.

If anyone wants to change this, you can see the splitting happening inside of org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportBulkAction.executeBulk() near the comment "go over all the request and create a ShardId". The individual requests happen a few lines down around line 293 on version 1.2.1.

Answer (score 6):

elasticsearch 1.3.4

our system 8 core * 2

4 bulk worker each insert 300,000 message per 1 min => 20,000 per sec

i'm also that exception! then set config

```
elasticsearch.yml

threadpool.bulk.type: fixed
threadpool.bulk.size: 8                 # availableProcessors
threadpool.bulk.queue_size: 500

source

BulkRequestBuilder bulkRequest = es.getClient().prepareBulk();

bulkRequest.setReplicationType  (ReplicationType.ASYNC).setConsistencyLevel(WriteConsistencyLevel.ONE);

loop begin
bulkRequest.add(es.getClient().prepareIndex(esIndexName, esTypeName).setSource(document.getBytes    ("UTF-8")));
loop end

BulkResponse bulkResponse = bulkRequest.execute().actionGet();
```

4core => bulk.size 4

then no error

Comment: curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_cluster/settings -d '{ "transient" : { "threadpool.bulk.queue_size" : 500 } }'

Comment: @PeterDietz I get "transient setting [threadpool.bulk.queue_size], not dynamically updateable".. any ideas? ES Version 5.1.2

Answer (score 3):

I was having this issue and my solution ended up being increasing `ulimit -Sn` and `ulimit Hn` for the elasticsearch user. I went from 1024 (default) to 99999 and things cleaned right up.