# Elastic search could not write all entries: May be es was overloaded

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, apache-spark-sql, elasticsearch-spark

I have an application where I read csv files and do some transformations and then push them to elastic search from spark itself. Like this

```
input.write.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
              .mode(SaveMode.Append)
              .option("es.resource", "{date}/" + type).save()
```

I have several nodes and in each node, I run 5-6 `spark-submit` commands that push to `elasticsearch`

I am frequently getting Errors

```
Could not write all entries [13/128] (Maybe ES was overloaded?). Error sample (first [5] error messages):
        rejected execution of org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$7@32e6f8f8 on EsThreadPoolExecutor[bulk, queue capacity = 200, org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.EsThreadPoolExecutor@4448a084[Running, pool size = 4, active threads = 4, queued tasks = 200, completed tasks = 451515]]
```

My Elasticsearch cluster has following stats -

```
Nodes - 9 (1TB space,
Ram >= 15GB ) More than 8 cores per node
```

I have modified following parameters for elasticseach

```
spark.es.batch.size.bytes=5000000
spark.es.batch.size.entries=5000
spark.es.batch.write.refresh=false
```

Could anyone suggest, What can I fix to get rid of these errors?

Comment: try to reduce entries, take a look on `iostat`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This occurs because the bulk requests are incoming at a rate greater than elasticsearch cluster could process and the bulk request queue is full.

The default bulk queue size is 200.

You should handle ideally  this on the client side :

1) by reducing the number the spark-submit commands running concurrently

2) Retry in case of rejections by tweaking the `es.batch.write.retry.count` and 
`es.batch.write.retry.wait`

Example:

```
es.batch.write.retry.wait = "60s"
es.batch.write.retry.count = 6
```

On elasticsearch cluster side :

1) check if there are too many shards per index and try reducing it.
This [blog](https://www.elastic.co/blog/how-many-shards-should-i-have-in-my-elasticsearch-cluster) has a good discussion on criteria for tuning the number of shards.

2) as a last resort increase the [thread_pool.index.bulk.queue_size](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-threadpool.html)

Check this [blog](https://www.elastic.co/blog/why-am-i-seeing-bulk-rejections-in-my-elasticsearch-cluster) with an extensive discussion on bulk rejections.

Comment: I have 90 Shards per index. Because I want to distribute data to each node (1TB storage, 9 nodes total) evenly. Otherwise some of nodes runs out of space while others have enough space.

Comment: @Hardcoder makes sense but could you try a multiplicative factor less than 10 . Example : 9*5 = 45. This blog has a good discussion on tuning number of shards . Edited answer to include the blog link

Comment: In my case when using spark we simply reduce the number of executors and repartition to deal with the ES speed insertion. Its a trick to avoid bulk insertion retries

Answer (score 0):

The bulk queue in your ES cluster is hitting its capacity (200) . Try increasing it. See this page for how to change the bulk queue capacity.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-threadpool.html

Also check this other SO answer where OP had a very similar issue and was fixed by increasing the bulk pool size.

[Rejected Execution of org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37855803/rejected-execution-of-org-elasticsearch-transport-transportservice-error)