# How to check current size of the ealastisearch queues defined in threadpool.XXX.queue_size?

Tags: elasticsearch, configuration, queue, size

How to check current size of the ealastisearch queues defined in threadpool.index.queue_size and threadpool.bulk.queue_size?

There is already some topic/question at SO related to the problems with queueing in the Elasticsearch: [ElasticSearch gives error about queue size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20683440/elasticsearch-gives-error-about-queue-size)

This is about how to set queue sizes. But how to read the current (in real time) size/load on those queues to avoid in runtime overloading Elasticsearch and or to see if they are optimally used and the lengths are properly set?

I had tried to find the answer in the [CAT API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/cat.html), but there is nothing explicit related to those queues (perhaps I do not see anything).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got the answer in at Elasticsearch forum: [How to check current size of the ealastisearch queues defined in threadpool.XXX.queue_size?](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-check-current-size-of-the-ealastisearch-queues-defined-in-threadpool-xxx-queue-size/69254/2)

The REST call:

```
curl -XGET "https://server:port/_nodes/thread_pool?v"
```

will return JSON and in the path nodes/thread_pool/index and nodes/thread_pool/bulk will be located information about queue sizes.

Something like:

```
"index" : {
    "type" : "fixed",
    "min" : 2,
    "max" : 2,
    "queue_size" : 1000
},
```

More on that topic can be found at: [Nodes Stats](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-nodes-stats.html)

Comment: As of Elasticsearch 5.6, the "v" query params is not supported. You can try "_nodes/thread_pool?pretty"